# Meaning of a phrase in a sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was reading a physics text where there was a sentence that goes like this,

> Motion is a combined property of the object under study and the observer.

I couldn't understand the sentence at first so thought about it for some time but got nothing so I asked it the physics stack exchange, they gave an explanation for this sentence that made sense and it seemed true but today I thought about this sentence again and looked for the meaning of the word 'combined' and I understood it and also looked for the meaning of the 'combined property' which I didn't understand but I do know it is not going to be the meaning that was intended in this sentence.  What I got from the explanation of the physics stack exchange of this sentence is that 'Motion(of an object) is dependent on both the object and the observer' and what I got from thinking about the sentence is 'Motion is a property of both the object and the observer'. As you can see there is a major difference in what I think the sentence means and what they explained it to be and mine seems to be completely illogical, I want to know the meaning of the phrase 'combined property' that is intended in here to understand this sentence. I need assistance.

Comment: No, I can't see that there is a 'major difference'. If something is moving, it is changing position relative to the observer. 'Property of' and 'dependent on' are just different ways of expressing that idea.

Comment: _Combined property_ is not an established phrase. So it must be taken as a property of the (system obtained by combining) the two elements.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of problems with the meaning of sentences. What is your native language?

Comment: @KateBunting- Motion is a phenomenon that is based on the observer and the object not a property of the observer at least like 'color' is a property of a material, motion simply just can't be a property(again at least for the observer).